# Disable OPTIONS Method Jetty Server

Tags: java, rest, web-applications, webserver, jetty

I have developed a web application which has set of GET and Post calls. I want to block my Jetty webserver for OPTIONS call.

Currently I get something like this in response.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 28 Apr 2015 07:41:50 GMT
Server: Apache
Allow: GET,HEAD,POST,OPTIONS
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Expires: Tue, 28 Apr 2015 07:41:50 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Content-Type: httpd/unix-directory
```

I dont want to ALLOW - Options method type. Can someone tell me how can I disable it from jetty servers property file? I am not able to find any property for this.

Comment: I'm curious... Why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable it for specific webapps using a technique similar to how TRACE is disabled.

See the jetty-distribution [`etc/webdefault.xml`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.2.10.v20150310/jetty-webapp/src/main/config/etc/webdefault.xml#L514-L531)

How to do this ...

Edit your webapp's `WEB-INF/web.xml` and add the following

```xml
  <!-- ==================================================================== -->
  <!-- Disable OPTIONS method with security constraint                      -->
  <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  -->
  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Disable OPTIONS</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
      <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint/>
  </security-constraint>
  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Enable everything but OPTIONS</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
      <http-method-omission>OPTIONS</http-method-omission>
    </web-resource-collection>
  </security-constraint>
```