# How do i disable options request method from being even processed in dropwizard

Tags: jersey, jetty, dropwizard, http-status-code-405, http-options-method

I send a curl command with OPTIONS request method to my dropwizard application. I get a 200 Ok and POST and OPTIONS methods allowed as response.

How do i stop this from happening for security reasons as this provides some info about what are supported.

I tried implementing a custom request filter that responds with **405 not allowed** for options method and added to a resource using NameBinding and  but I think OPTIONS request does not reach at that point and so I am still getting 200OK  and the same POST, OPTIONS plain text response.

I also tried using CrossOriginFilter.class in environment.servlets.addFilter() and configured it to not allow OPTIONS request. but that also did not work.

I got another post here :
[Disable OPTIONS Method Jetty Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29914531/disable-options-method-jetty-server?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

but how do i achieve this in dropwizard via java code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out,

In context of dropwizard:

Two ways to achieve this are

1. [Easy way] Create a request filter and filter based on a list of URLs that you want to disable OPTIONS request.
2. [Cool way] If you want to do with an annotation based filter like `@OptionsFilter` on a specific API resource method.

Detailed 2nd method:
First , you need to extend `ApplicationEventListener` and register all such methods 
and during `APPLICATION_START` event (using reflection). 
Then, you also extend `RequestEventListener` and listen to the event and then find the method from the `uriInfo` which you get in `request context` and then check in the list of methods that you created at application startup.  For more sample implementation, see how `@UnitOfWork` annotation works and sets the `SessionFactory` for a resource method.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the OPTIONS request on a global application level in DW by specifying which methods are allowed on the YAML configuration file:

```
server:
  allowedMethods:
  - GET
```

The applications is now returning 405 on all OPTION requests.

Comment: can i not do it for a url pattern only ?